# Programmatically submit user reset password form

Tags: 7, forms

I have a register form that I am able to submit programmatically without any problems.

However when I try to do the same with the user reset password form, it doesn't send me any emails, nor does it do any validation.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['name'] = $_POST['username'];
$form_state['values']['submit'] = t('E-mail me new password');

drupal_form_submit('user_pass_form', $form_state);
```

Note: I've tried using `user_pass` instead of `user_pass_form`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is this:

```
global $language;
$account = user_load_by_name($username);
if ($account) {
// Mail one time login URL and instructions using current language.
$mail = _user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account, $language);
  if (!empty($mail)) {
    watchdog('user', 'Password reset instructions mailed to %name at %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
  }
}
```

Essentially all you need is:

```
_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account, $language);
```

More info: [user_pass_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_pass_submit/7)

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the username you are submitting is valid?  If it isn't, this will fail validation.  In addition, it is a bad practice to use $_POST directly in Drupal.
It should also definitely be drupal_form_submit('user_pass',... not 'user_pass_form'.